# How to make Radio buttons with centered and proportional images instead of text?

Tags: android, radio-button, imagebutton

Before marking as solved, many topics tackle this problem, but non give a good solution.

I want to create `radio buttons` with centered and proportionally sized images, in an adaptive `RadioGroup` (`android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`)

Solutions that **DON'T** work:

1. setting `android:button="R.drawable.x"` or `android:drawableStart="R.drawable.x"` and its siblings - the image will be drawn off-center, hovering around an invisible text

Example:

```
`<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_home"
        style="@style/radio_btn_style"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn_home_selector"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_discover"
        style="@style/radio_btn_style"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn_discover_selector"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_my_profile"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn_my_profile_selector"
        android:checked="true"
        style="@style/radio_btn_style"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bt_new_activity"
        style="@style/radio_btn_style"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn_add_activity_selector"

        />


</RadioGroup>`
```

Result: radio buttons are off-center

---

2. setting `android:background="R.drawable.x"` - image will *smear* to fill the background.

Example:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_home"
        style="@style/radio_btn_style"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_home_selector"
        android:button="@null"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_discover"
        style="@style/radio_btn_style"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_discover_selector"
        android:button="@null"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_my_profile"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_my_profile_selector"
        android:checked="true"
        style="@style/radio_btn_style"
        android:button="@null"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/bt_new_activity"
        style="@style/radio_btn_style"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_btn_add_activity_selector"
        android:button="@null"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Result: [background icons get smeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkLHG.png)

---

3. setting `RadioButton` `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` - bunches buttons to center, but does not space out evenly throughout `RadioGroup` width

Result: radio buttons bunched

---

**This is the result I wan't:**
[radio buttons spaced out evenly, maintaining image proportion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9jlA.png)

Any ideas? Thanks...

---

P.S.:
the used style:

```
`<style name="radio_btn_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>

 </style>`
```

drawable selector example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_nav_home_selected"
 android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_nav_home"/>
 </selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you better use BottomNavigationView

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0#.95osn0hy9

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="kostas.testexample.com.testexample.MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                style="@style/radio_btn_style"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/radio_btn_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/radio_btn_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                style="@style/radio_btn_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then modify your style like:

```
<style name="radio_btn_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:scaleX">0.5</item>
        <item name="android:scaleY">0.6</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/example</item>

    </style>
```

and it will give you the following result:

[image]

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: thanks, but this still causes the problem that images will smear on different screen sizes...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this widget

```
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

Hope this will solve your problem.